# HasMany Relationship to Create Record - Why is undefined?

Tags: javascript, has-many

I have an issue which relates to a "HasMany Relationship to Create Record" but I have looked and tried the answers that are already on stack overflow and they don't work. The issue is that the model is undefined. I have combined the QuestionsController and TopicController.

This is the model for Topic:

```js
App.Topic = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
    questions: DS.hasMany('Question', {async: true}),
});

App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Early America',
    questions: [1,2]
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   title: 'American Revolution',
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   title: 'Modern America',
 }
];
```

This is the TopicsController:

```
App.TopicsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 

    actions: {
        createTopic: function () {
            var Topic = this.store.createRecord('Topic', {
                title: 'Untitled Topic'
            });
            /* Topic.get(questions.find(1)... */
            Topic.save();

            this.set('newTitle', '');
        },
    }
});
```

This is the TopicController:

```
App.TopicController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        editTopic: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
        removeTopic: function () {
            var topic = this.get('model');

            topic.deleteRecord();
            topic.save();
        },
        createQuestion: function () {
            var question = this.get('store').createRecord('Question', {
                title: 'Untitled Question',
                topic: this.get('model'),
            });
            question.save();
        }
    }   
});
```

This is the model for question:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    topic: DS.belongsTo('Topic', {async: true}),
});

App.Question.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'What continent did Colombus find?',
   topic: 1,
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   title: 'Other question',
 },
];
```

And this is the QuestionController:

```
App.QuestionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
   isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        editQuestion: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
        removeQuestion: function () {
            console.log(this);
                        console.log("hello");
                        var question = this.get('model');

                        question.deleteRecord();
                        question.save();
        }
    }
});
```

This is where all the files are stored: https://github.com/Glorious-Game-Design-ASL/MapQuizGame/tree/master/quiz_creator

Answer (score 0):

Phew, that took a while to figure out. I have a [minimal, without the styling or the bells-and-whistles] working example here: https://gist.github.com/polerc/8137422

**Summary:**

Basically, the `TopicsController` and the `QuestionsController` are too much layering. Merge `TopicsController` into `QuizController` and merge `QuestionsController` into `TopicController`.